# How to use Groovy script in soapUi to loop multiple time

Tags: groovy, scripting, soapui

I am new to SoapUi. I am exploring on how multiple request in soapUi is done using groovy script.

below is the example that im trying to do, based on example that i found through "googling"

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner
import java.util.Random 
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.Status



// Define your testCase pointer
//def testcase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite - User Management REST API"].getTestCaseByName ("Authenticate User")

def counterUser = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "counter" )

int value = counterUser.toInteger()
String tester = ""
30.times {
 value = value + 1
 tester = "tester " + value.toString()
 testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "userName", tester )

 testRunner.runTestStepByName("POST - createUser - Create a User")
}
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "counter", value.toString() )
```

I want to create a 30 users which start from Tester1...tester2.....tester30.
Is it possible to do this way? I keep getting an error such as **NullPointerException** at this line

```
int value = counterUser.toInteger()
```

Comment: Can you please add full stacktrace from `error log` tab?

Comment: `Fri Oct 06 13:51:32 SGT 2017:ERROR:An error occurred [Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object], see error log for details`

do i need to import anything else more?

Comment: annie, check the solution to see if that resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what you say.

That is because, initially there is no value for counter which results to `null` and you are applying `toInteger()` over it.

Just change:

**From:**

```
int value = counterUser.toInteger()
```

**To:**

```
int value = counterUser?.toInteger() ?: 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it right! But the number keep increasing when i run multiple times. now it become tester340 after i run many times.

Comment: Hi - re-initialise the counter to zero in your last line.  I'm guessing the values being written back after each test is 30, 60, 90.....